# Confusion about projectile

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile

> Yesterday i got a MCQ in exam that a body in projectile motion with initial velocity 20m/s creating an angle of 60 degree with horizontal. What is its velocity at max. Height
>
> (A) 10m/s
>
> Or
>
> (B) 0m/s?

I think that it should be 10m/s but all friends are saying that it is 0m/s. Please tell me where am i getting it wrong.
Because i think only vertical velocity is 0m/s at max. Height so the velocity of projectile would be only horizontal component of initial velocity.
$V = V_i \cos(\theta)$.

Comment: You're absolutely right.

Comment: What's an "MCQ"? Always explain non-ubiquitious abbreviations the first time you use them!

Comment: "MCQ" is a multiple choice question.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. The horizontal component of velocity is constant at $v_x = V_i \cos \theta$. The vertical component varies by $v_y = V_i \sin \theta - g t$.

Together the speed at any point is $$ v = \sqrt{v_x^2 + v_y^2} = \sqrt{V_i^2 + (g t)^2 - 2 V_i (g t) \sin \theta}$$

At the top of $v_y=0$ (by definition) then $v=V_i \cos \theta$ as you mentioned.

Comment: So it means the correct answer is 10m/s

Comment: Is there any doubt left? I suppose you can find the numeric result on your own.